# Machine Learning: Basics DepreciationWarning

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, svm

I'm running a basic machine learning tutorial code snippet (which compiles properly on the computer of the person teaching), and I can't seem to find what's wrong. I understand the question has been 'answered', but I can't seem to understand the answer.

> DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
>     DeprecationWarning)
>   [0]

Apparently I just use X.reshape(-1, 1) or X.reshape(1, -1), but I'm not sure exactly how either work in a general situation, or if they should be placed before or after I plot/for the data.

Here's my source code. Any help is much appreciated :-)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn import svm

x = [1, 5, 1.5, 8, 1, 9]
y = [2, 8, 1.8, 8, 0.6, 11]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()

X = np.array([[1,2],
            [5,8],
            [1.5,1.8],
            [8,8],
            [1,0.6],
            [9,11]])

y = [0,1,0,1,0,1]

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 1.0)


clf.fit(X,y)

print(clf.predict([0.58,0.76]))
```

Comment: `deprecation` != `depreciation`... "about to be obsolete" v.s "losing monetary value".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your point. Reading another post about the same issue I'm under the impression X had to be a 2D array and y had to be 1D, which is the case. I'm unclear why the error is occurring (esp. because it doesn't happen in the tutorial I'm watching) and what it means exactly.

Comment: look at your title... typo

Comment: @MarcB It is not a typo on D. Wang's behalf. That is the exact text from the warning message.

Comment: Interesting. Guess the app itself has a typo, then. it uses both in the error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data has more than a single feature and it contains more than a single sample you are fine. This is just a warning and shouldn't interfere with the algorithm's behavior.

Comment: Ah, alright. I'm a total novice at the moment, so I just wanted to know if the error affected anything, and what it meant. Thanks a lot!